# SAS Subquerying population

Tags: postgresql, sas

I wonder if there is a way to query in SAS to select a subgroup, just like select option in Postgres

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    s.diagnoses 
WHERE   icd9code = ANY    ('{2910,2911,2912,2913,2914,2915,3456,3457,3458}');
```

Also is there way to specify ranges instead of the actual value eg: between 2910-2915

The diagnosis codes are characters not numeric. I am using the SAS University Edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to specify range then you have to convert the character field into numeric and then give the range

```
   /***** if you want to mention each icd9code*****/
   data have;
   set diagnoses (where=(icd9code in ('2910' '2911' '2912' '2913' '2914' '2915' '3456' '3457' '3458')));
   run;  

   /***** if you want to give range *****/
   data have;
   set diagnoses;
   if input(icd9code ,4.) >= 2910 and input(icd9code ,4.) <= 3458;
   run;
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: The icd9 codes in my data range from 0001 to 9999. Using greater than or less than logic will select other icd9 codes which I am not interested. For instance, I want to select patients with icd9 code 2915 and not 2916.

Comment: then you can differenet greater than less than logics for different ranges. eg: if (input(icd9code ,4.) >= 2910 and input(icd9code ,4.) <= 2915) or (input(icd9code ,4.) >= 2918 and input(icd9code ,4.) <= 2920)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a character you cannot use the range. But you can use the `in` statement

```
SELECT  * FROM    s.diagnoses WHERE   icd9code in    ('2910','2911','2912');
```

Answer (score 0):

To select range. You can define your own macro to generate strings of range like this

```
%macro range(start, stop);
    %if &start. = &stop. %then %do;
        "&stop."
    %end;
    %else %do;
        "&start.", %range(%sysevalf(&start+1), &stop);
    %end;
%mend range;

%put %range(2910, 2915);
* -> "2910", "2911", "2912", "2913", "2914", "2915"
```

Then assign it to a macro variable and use it in you where statement within **proc sql**

```
%let subset1 = %range(2910, 2915);
proc sql noprint;
    create table want as
    select *
    from 
    have
    where var_want in (&subset1.);
quit;
```

You can then define multiple subset variables with different ranges and combination them in where condition to achieve more complex subsetting.

Answer (score 0):

For ranges you want to include in their entirety, you can use inequalities directly - no 'input' required, as long as you have leading zeros, and for the rest you can use `in`, e.g.

```
data example;
length char $1;
do i = 64 to 100;
  char = byte(i);
  output;
end;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
    select * from example where 'A' <= char <= 'Z' or char in ('[',']');
quit;
```